# Check all extensions from a multiple upload file input

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change this code so that the condition checks the file extensions of all the selected files from multiple select file input, this code only checks for one. Any way I can do this?

```
var file = document.getElementById('file');
var ext = file.value.substring(file.value.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

     if(ext!== "mp4" && ext!== "m4v" && ext!== "f4v")  {
         alert('not an accepted file extension');
             return false;
} 

<input id="file" name="uploaded[]" type="file" multiple />
```

Comment: Looks like you are off to a good start. What else have you tried or researched to get closer to a solution?

Comment: I googled around but couldn't find much on it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note I only bothered to get the last three characters of the string because you only have three letter file extensions. If you wanted you could use `.split('.')` to get an array of segments and choose the last element of that array.

```
var selection = document.getElementById('file');
for (var i=0; i<selection.files.length; i++) {
    var ext = selection.files[i].name.substr(-3);
    if(ext!== "mp4" && ext!== "m4v" && ext!== "fv4")  {
        alert('not an accepted file extension');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you did! thanks for that I appreciate the effort. accepted answer for sure. :D

Comment: @user1559811 Just want to make sure you aware that != and !== are two similar but different operators. It won't make a difference here, but it's something worth knowing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: I didn't know that i always thought it was only ==, === and !==. I should learn more about that, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the input elements within an array of dom elements use `document.getElementsByName('uploaded[]')`.

For example in your case it would be something like:

```
var files = document.getElementsByName('uploaded[]'); 
for (var i = 0, j = files.length; i < j; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    // do stuff with your file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple files validation through javascript [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```js
function isVideo(film) {
  const ext = ['.mp4', '.m4v', '.fv4'];
  return ext.some(el => film.endsWith(el));
}

function fileValidation() {
  let files = document.getElementById('file');
  for (let i = 0; i < files.files.length; ++i) {
    let fname = files.files.item(i).name;
    if (!isVideo(fname)) {
      alert("File extension not supported!");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="file" name="uploaded[]" type="file" multiple onchange="fileValidation()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input name="" id="yourinputfieldis"  onchange="checkFile()"  type="file" multiple = "multiple" accept = "*">    

  <script>
        function checkFile() {   
        var x =  document.getElementById("yourinputfieldis");
        var txt = "";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        if ('files' in x) {
        if (x.files.length == 0) {
        txt = "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {      

        var file = x.files[i];
        if ('name' in file) {

        var ext = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg','doc','pdf','xlsx']) == -1) {
        txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("yourinputfieldis").value = "";

        if ('size' in file) {
        txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
        }
        alert('You are trying to upload files which not allowed ' + "(" + file.name + " is invalid)");

        }

        }
        }
        }
        }
        else {
        if (x.value == "") {
        txt += "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
        txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
        txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value; 
        }
        }     
        }
   </script>
```

Comment: could you please add some information how your solution solves the problem?

Comment: you can upload multiple files and check all the extentions.
            ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg','doc','pdf','xlsx']
after one by one check and block undifine file extention

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to validate file types in aspx page,

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fupload" name="fupload" runat="server" Class="form-control multi" accept="doc|docx|pdf|xls|xlsx" Width="270px" />
```

And I have used "MultiFile.js" plugin to choose Multiple file and Upload.